# Print score and High score

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I try to explain better the situation.

The variables are:

```
int punteggio;

CCLabelTTF *labelPunteggio;
```

Then in the init metod i print my score on the screen:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {

    // PUNTEGGIO
    labelPunteggio = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0000" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:13];

    [self addChild:labelPunteggio];
    ....
    }
}
```

And this is the function to add score on Punteggio: for example, every time i kill a monster i add 10 point.

```
-(void)aggiungiPunti
{
    punteggio = punteggio +0001;

    [labelPunteggio setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", punteggio]];
}
```

But now, i don't know how save the score when the player do game over.
I'd want save this score, and then print the high score on the screen,
i think about

```
-(void) setScore:(int)score
{
    punteggio = highScore;

    if (punteggio>highScore)
    {
        highScore = punteggio;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setScore method is certain not to work since you set highScore = punteggio, the if will never be true.  try:

```
-(void) setHighScore:(int) newScore {
    if(newScore>highScore) highScore = newScore;
}
```

and every time you update the current score

```
-(void)aggiungiPunti
{
    punteggio = punteggio +0001;
    [labelPunteggio setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", punteggio]];
    [self setHighScore:punteggio];
}
```

this way your highScore variable will always be set, whatever the state of game play. Dont forget to set highScore at the beginning of the current game to the current highScore you must have persisted somewhere.

Comment: Thank u! I try but doesn't work...
i print in init metod like this         labelScore = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0000" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:13];
        
        [self addChild:labelScore];
        
        
        labelhighScore = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:13];
        
        [self addChild:labelhighScore];

Score change but highscore is always 0.